# Matrix equation - find $a,b,c,d$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How do I find a,b,c and d in this matrix equation?
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 2a \\
    b & -2 \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    b & -a \\
    c & d \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & 2 \\
    2 & 6 \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$

So far, I've worked out $d$ by using doing 6-(-2) which equals to 8. I'm not so sure on how to work out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Adding each component:
$$3+b=a$$
$$2a-a=2$$
$$b+c=2$$
$$-2+d=6$$
I'm sure you can work out the rest.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had done before as well. But for example, for the first one - how do I work out b or a if I only have 3 there? This is what I'm confused about here. I'm also having the same problems for the second and third one.

Comment: You can use the result of another equation. For example, equation 2 gives you $a$. Then use that value of $a$ in the first equation, you can solve for $b$.

Comment: You have 4 linear equations in 4 unknowns. Have you not learned how to solve such a system, Penny? It seems strange that you would be asked to do such a question before you've been taught to solve systems of linear equations.

Comment: Are you still here, Penny?